# Android adapter.getItem(position).getItemId() not working (The method getId() is undefined for the type Object)

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem, android-adapter

I have a listview and i am populating the data to the list view form DB using custom adapter. Its working fine, but when i click on the list item, i want to get the ID of the item which is clicked to pass it on to the next activity to do some stuff. But when i click on list item, i am not able to get the ID.
Any idea why is this happening?

my list listener:

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position,
                        long id) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            CountryActivity.class);
                     intent.putExtra("countryId", adapter.getItem(position).getId());//here i am getting error saying 
          //The method getId() is undefined for the type Object.

                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```

But i have defined my countries.java (POJO) for type specification

```
public class Countries {
    Integer id;
    String countryName = "", countryIcon = "";

    public Countries(Integer id, String countryName, String countryIcon) {

        this.id = id;
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.countryIcon = countryIcon;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public String getCountryIcon() {
        return countryIcon;
    }

    public void setCountryIcon(String countryIcon) {
        this.countryIcon = countryIcon;
    }

}
```

i am fetching data out of cursor obj (visas) from the below code:

```
names = new ArrayList<Countries>();
        do {

            country = new Countries(Integer.parseInt(visas.getString(0)),
                    visas.getString(1), visas.getString(2));

            // Log.d("VISA", visas.getString(0));

            names.add(country);

        } while (visas.moveToNext());
```

here is my adapter code:

```
public class VisaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Countries> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Countries> values;
    Resources resc = getContext().getResources();

    public VisaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Countries> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public Countries getItem(int position) {
        return values.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        textView.setText(values.get(position).getCountryName());

        // Change icon based on name
        String icon = values.get(position).getCountryIcon();
        int resIcon = resc.getIdentifier(icon, "drawable", "com.m7.visaapp");

        rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_view_places_row);

        imageView.setImageResource(resIcon);

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to create `values` inside `VisaAdapter` (`ArrayAdapter` already stores them...no need for duplication) and you don't need to override `getItem` as what you have is the default implementation anyways.

Comment: Can you show us where you declare the `adapter` variable?

Comment: @Tushar thanks for the answers. David's answer works. But if i remove values from VisaAdapter, how can i get reference to inflate the data onto listview, for example : values.get(position).getCountryName());

Comment: You'd use `getItem(position).getCountryName()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must cast the `getItem(position)` return value to a `Countries` object.

Change this:

```
    intent.putExtra("countryId", adapter.getItem(position).getId());
```

To this:

```
    Countries countries = (Countries)adapter.getItem(position);
    intent.putExtra("countryId", countries.getId());
```

---

**Update**:

Actually, after reading @Tushar's comment, I think you should make `names` a `VisaAdapter` instead of an `ArrayList<Countries>()`. Then, your original line of code, above, should work as-is.

Comment: This may fix the problem, but it shouldn't be the case. Look up the signature of `getItem()`

Comment: You're right @Tushar. I've edited my answer based on your input. If you add an answer of your own, suresh would do best to accept yours as correct.

Comment: its working, in my case, StateBean stateBean = (StateBean) stateAdapter.getItem(position);
                mEditTextState.setText(stateBean.getName());
                mStateId = stateBean.getId();

Answer (score 6):

```
adapter.getItem(position)
```

function Returns an `Object` so type cast it to Country like

```
(Countries)adapter.getItem(position)
```

Comment: Does it? You should look up the signature of `getItem`. `ArrayAdapter<T>.getItem()` returns `T`.

Comment: adapter I am also concerned about the type of adapter variable ?

Comment: ((ConvoResponseModel.DataBean.ConversationBean) adapter.getItemId(0)).getTime();  i am trying it this way but getting inconvertible cannot cast long to ConversationBean how do i solve this?